# Why angular does not populate view in dynamically created component?

Tags: angular, angular8

I have a component that using third party map library. `MousePositionComponent` is in my `MapModule`.

```
@Component({
  ....,
  template: `<span>{{coordinate}}</span>`
})
export class MousePositionComponent implements OnInit {

  public coordinate: string;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.map.on("click", this.onMapClicked());
  }

  private onMapClicked(): (evt: MapBrowserEvent) => void {
    return (event: MapBrowserEvent) => {
      let coordinate = this.transformCoordinate(event.coordinate);
      this.coordinate = this.formatCoordinate(coordinate);
      console.log(this.coordinate)
    }
  }
}
```

So I am using `MapModule` in my `ApplicationModule`. If I use in a dynamically created `SommeComponent`, it works. If I have `AnotherComponent` that dynamically created, the view does not update, but `console.log(this.coordinate)` works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the function executes outside Angular's zone, so you need to tell it explicitly, to run change detection on click event

```
constructor(private ngZone:NgZone){

}



 ngOnInit() {
    this.map.on("click", this.ngZone.run(()=>this.onMapClicked()));
  }

  private onMapClicked(): (evt: MapBrowserEvent) => void {
    return (event: MapBrowserEvent) => {
      let coordinate = this.transformCoordinate(event.coordinate);
      this.coordinate = this.formatCoordinate(coordinate);
      console.log(this.coordinate)
    }
  }
```

Comment: How to remove event ngOnDestroy?

Comment: reference this callback somewhere in components field and on ngOnDestroy call thiss.map.removeEventListener("click",callbackReference)

Comment: But we put `this.ngZone.run()` function in `this.map.on` method. So I think use for removing like  `this.mapComponent.map.un("click", this.ngZone.run(() => this.onMapClicked()));` is it true?